# Sound Icon Red With Dashes

Tags: sound, indicator-sound

Why does the sound icon turn red with dashes whenever I attempt to play something with sound?

Sound Icon With Red Dashes When Attempting to Play Something [image: Sound Icon With Red Dashes When Attempting to Play Something]

Normal Sound Icon When Not Attempting to Play Something [image: Normal Sound Icon When Not Attempting to Play Something]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It means sound is muted.

It is confusing that the icon sometimes appears with the dashes as illustrated above, and sometimes the normal icon, as though the sound is changing state even though the mute state is not being changed.

Answer (score 0):

The dashes are the normal indicator that you have sound muted. The red is an extra reminder that happens when you try to play sound while it's still muted.

Comment: That's not correct.  See additional icon in original question.

Comment: Perhaps your volume is at 0% but not technically muted then. (The second picture wasn't there when I first answered.)